# Error with Spatial Analysis Toolbox & Toolkit

Tags: qgis, spatial-analysis, toolbox

I have been trying to resolve this for some days in response to an error while installing plugins. What can I do?

> Python error: Couldn't load plugin 'spatialanalysistoolbox' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more detail

```
INFO    Application state:
 QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr
 Prefix: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr
 Plugin Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr/plugins
 Package Data Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr/.
 Active Theme Name: default
 Active Theme Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr/./resources/themes\default\icons/
 Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
 SVG Search Paths: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr/./svg/
  C:/Users/crack/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/svg/
 User DB Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.7/apps/qgis-ltr/./resources/qgis.db
 Auth DB Path: C:/Users/crack/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/qgis-auth.db
```

Comment: Did you pip install [all the dependencies](https://github.com/parmendel/spatialanalysistoolbox)? That plugin won't load and will raise that exception if you don't.